# IOS app keeps crashing because of highscore

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

After trying to submit my game to the app store, my app got rejected because of some bug that's working on an iPad 2. I tried to find the problem, and it was because of some high score bug. This happens when the player gets 0 for the first time, right on the scene that shows your score and high score. Here's the code:

```
var highScoreDefault = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()

//Right below is the problem
highScore = highScoreDefault.valueForKey("highScore") as NSInteger
```

Here's the error I get if I get 0 for the first time:

> EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_1386_INVOP,subcode=0x0)

I keep trying to find a different but a simple way to add the high score, but I can't find it. Please help!

Note: I'm running on Xcode 6.2 in Swift, and this happened on all iOS simulators.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without more code... Try just make `if let` statement

something like:

```
if let value = highScoreDefault.valueForKey("highScore") as? NSInteger {
    highScore = value
} else {
    highScore = 0
}
```

Comment: It worked! It's not crashing anymore! Thanks so much!